# To extract specific word from excel based on two criterias

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge data in excel sheet in which i have to see if a word (part 1) or (part 2) comes in any cell in Column A it should copy this specific word (Part 1) (part 2) in Column b, otherwise it returns with (blank) or (-)

I am able to search and copy if there is a word (Part 1) in cell by using the formula =if(isnumber(search("Part 1",A1)),"Part 1","-")  but i am not able to look two criteria.

please see e.g. in screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any solution or if anyone can guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula, it will check for both conditions and return answer accordingly.
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Part 1",A1)),"Part 1",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Part 2",A2)),"Part 2","_"))

Hope you'll find this helpful..

Comment: @SalmanShafi note that `SEARCH()` is not case sensitive, while `FIND()` is, since the screenshot you have shown as output it needs `FIND()` and not `SEARCH()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula:

`=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("Part ",A1), 6),"-")`

It looks for "Part " - and returns the substring if found - by that you avoid having an extra condition for Part 1 and Part 2

Comment: I thought this one was more eloquent solution. Because it is dynamic and works for both. We dont require two `IF()`. Sometimes I dont understand what OP needs